# Difference between calling a "project" function and calling a DLL function

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, loadlibrary

I currently have a C++ sample calling for a C++ DLL function this way:

```
typedef BOOL(__stdcall *f_funci)(const char*, char*);

HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary(L"myDLL.dll");
f_funci DoSmth= (f_funci)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "function");

std::string test = "The cake is a lie, it's actually a Brownie...";

char *out = new char[124];
DoSmth(&test[0], out);
```

And the DLL function prototype:

```
BOOL function(const char *in, char *out){}
```

The problem is, when I call this DLL function, I got a totally random result at `in[x]` (whatever `x` value) (using Visual Studio debugger).

However, if I simply paste this function inside my `.cpp`, `in[x]` is always the result I would expect to have.

What I verified:

- DLL function's calling convention is stdcall, as expected.
- Both the sample and the DLL are in the following context - Debug - x64 -

What I think it could possibly come from but don't know enough to ensure a Yes/No answer:

- Memory management difference between a "simple call" and a GetProcAddress?
- Debugger issue (would be weird considering the out value is also false in dll call case)
- Other?

Please consider asking for details if something is unclear.

Comment: Just curious... change `std::string test` to an array of `char`and see if the behavior is any different.

Comment: @ap-osd: You asked for that clarification in your comment, that should have been enough; I flagged your (not-really-being-an-) answer (which is really just re-stating the above question) for deletion. Especially since passing the result of `c_str()` / `data()` to a function taking a C string (`const char *`) is very much well-defined; that part of your "answer" is off the mark -- and even while not being that well-defined, even passing `&test[0]` _should_ not be a problem.

Comment: @DevSolar - I just wanted to highlight the fact that the internal memory of `std::string` can change and is not reliable to hold on it. See references http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/ and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str. In any case, I will limit my answer to the specific problem.

Comment: @ap-osd: It is no more or less unreliable as passing a `const char *` directly. If you are looking at single-thread it *is* safe, if you are looking at multithreading it is safe unless you start modifying the string object (just like you could be modifying the C string object, e.g. freeing or reallocing its memory). It's a red herring.

Comment: @DevSolar - In theory that is fair. But I've had similar problems passing `std::string` across dlls. Maybe you can explain better as to why it happens and I will be happy to delete my "incorrect" answer.

Comment: @ap-osd: Passing `std::string` across DLL borders can be problematic because of differences in object representation. But the OP is *not* passing a `std::string`, but a `const char *` which only so happens to be currently under the _control_ of a `std::string`. Nothing to see here...

Comment: Correction... nothing to see here if OP went through `c_str()` / `data()`, which would be the correct way to do it - although there is no way I can think of right now that a conforming implementation could not work with `&test[0]` as well.

Comment: If the function really is prototyped as `BOOL function(const char *in, char *out)` then there is no calling convention specified, so it is likely using `__cdecl` and not `__stdcall` like you claim.  Unless you have your compiler configured to use `__stdcall` as its default calling convention.  Although, that only applies to a 32bit build, as such calling conventions don't apply to 64bit, there is only one 64bit calling convention as dictated by the 64bit ABI. Did you verify that `GetProcAddress()` is successful and `DoSmth` is not NULL?

Comment: I compiled the dll as __stdcall. But i do not know if it applies, i just verified the options was correctly set.

However, i did verified using if(!hGetProcAddress) and if(!DoSomething) and they both seems not to enter the if statement.

Also, i correctly enter (& return) the function, it's just that the debugger return me weird value.

Something important i forgot to mention is that i'm using UTF8 char in my 'in' parameter. But it seems to be easily supported if called in the .cpp function.

Answer (score 0):

Hum... I found the solution but i don't know how it could have solved anything...

I actually just recompiled the dll (using the same options, same format and stuff) and now the results are fine and it works well.

If someone has an explanation or a clue for that, i'm in.

Thanks for all replies and help !

Comment: That could be just about anything. Probably you were testing against an outdated binary. Perhaps you did set the DLL to __stdcall but forgot to recompile.

Comment: Note that it might be a good idea to delete your question, as it was resolved in a way that is unlikely to help other visitors.